# How to parse a text file and extract a varying amount of matches per line?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a text file that contains several tables, which each have their own header that spreads multiple lines. I am basically working along the lines of [this tutorial](https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/#step-5-write-a-file-parser).

My document basically contains multiple tables that are always structured like this:

```
Report Title



  AutoChem II 2920 V5.03    Unit  1    Serial # 937    Page 1  

     Sample:    SAMPLE_NAME    
   Operator:    Jane Doe                              
  Submitter:    ABCD                              
       File:    FILE_PATH 

    Started:    20.03.2020 8:17:56     Sample Mass:      0.4639 g           
  Completed:    20.03.2020 23:01:48    Report Time:    24.03.2020 12:18:36  

Comments: Comment





TCD Signal (a.u.) vs. Temperature


TCD Signal (a.u.) - NO2 TPD, 650C, 1.5h ads, 1.h flush, TPD He
Temperature (°C)    TCD Signal (a.u.)
120                  -0
120.024              0.000154972
120.028              -5.48363e-005
120.014              0.000126362
120.036              9.53674e-005
...
```

Using a regular expression dictionary

```
rx_dict = {
    'sample': re.compile(r'Sample: (?P<sample>.*)\n'),
    'operator': re.compile(r'Operator: (?P<operator>.*)\n'),
    'started': re.compile(r'Started: (?P<started>.*)\n'),
    'comments': re.compile(r'Comments: (?P<comments>.*)\n'),
}
```

and a line parser like this

```
def _parse_line(line):
    """
    Do a regex search against all defined regexes and
    return the key and match result of the first matching regex

    """

    for key, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            print(key)
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None
```

I am able to extract the sample name, the operator and starting time. However now I am facing two problems:

1. The starting time also includes the sample mass. I could of course split this afterwards, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.
2. I also want to detect the beginning of the table. So in this case the current `_parse_line` function is not working because it expects a key and a matching expression. How can I work around this?

Comment: Two questions: Does each table start with `Report Title`? What exactly is your expected output from the sample table in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can be a bit more precise with *all* of your regular expressions and then you won't have difficulty matching just the `Started` value (see below). Also, you can be more efficient by creating one regular expression and doing an iterative search:

```
import re

report = """Report Title



  AutoChem II 2920 V5.03    Unit  1    Serial # 937    Page 1

     Sample:    SAMPLE_NAME
   Operator:    Jane Doe
  Submitter:    ABCD
       File:    FILE_PATH

    Started:    20.03.2020 8:17:56     Sample Mass:      0.4639 g
  Completed:    20.03.2020 23:01:48    Report Time:    24.03.2020 12:18:36

Comments: Comment
"""

# Not a dictionary!
# If you are stuck with a passed dictionary whose values are compiled regular expressions, then:
# rx_list = map(lambda v: v.pattern, rx_list.values())
rx_list = [
    r'Sample:\s+(?P<sample>.*)\n',
    r'Operator:\s+(?P<operator>.*)\n',
    r'Started:\s+(?P<started>\d+\.\d+\.\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)',
    r'Comments:\s+(?P<comments>.*)\s*'
]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(rx_list))
# each iteration just matches one element of the report
d = {}
for m in regex.finditer(report):
    key = m.lastgroup # this is the one and only group name matched
    value = m[key]
    print(key, '->', value) # you can add these key and values to a dictionary, if you wish:
    d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
sample -> SAMPLE_NAME
operator -> Jane Doe
started -> 20.03.2020 8:17:56
comments -> Comment
{'sample': 'SAMPLE_NAME', 'operator': 'Jane Doe', 'started': '20.03.2020 8:17:56', 'comments': 'Comment'}
```